# Convert array of objects into an object with some changes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array as follow,

```
data = [
{
 "is_new":1,
 "is_delayed":24,
 "is_active":25,
 "name":"london"
},
{
 "is_new":1,
 "is_delayed":90,
 "is_active":90,
 "name":"paris"
},
{
 "is_new":1,
 "is_delayed":45,
 "is_active":45,
 "name":"India"
}
]
```

I want to convert objects in array in normal object with *"is_delayed"* and *"is_action"* value as 0 and 1 for each object.

So my final expected object will look as follows:

```
myObj = {
 "is_new":1,
 "is_delayed":0,
 "is_active":1,
 "name":"london"
},
{
 "is_new":1,
 "is_delayed":0,
 "is_active":1,
 "name":"paris"
},
{
 "is_new":1,
 "is_delayed":0,
 "is_active":1,
 "name":"India"
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create an array with new objects having the updated properties.

```js
let data=[{is_new:1,is_delayed:24,is_active:25,name:"london"},{is_new:1,is_delayed:90,is_active:90,name:"paris"},{is_new:1,is_delayed:45,is_active:45,name:"India"}];
let res = data.map(o => ({...o, is_delayed: 0, is_active: 1}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I don't need output in array. I need a object

Comment: @Rosy Your expected output isn't a valid object. What do you actually want?

Comment: means I don't want array sqaure brackets [].

Comment: @Rosy That's not a valid structure. You would need multiple variables to store multiple objects separately without an array. Can you explain why you need that?